# How do you setup Hyperledger Fabric OSNs to communicate with Kafka cluster over SSL?

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have followed http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/kafka.html to bring up a Kafka cluster and followed the link in step 9 (https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka/ssl.html) to make my Kafka cluster use SSL but I don't understand how to create the keys and configure the OSNs.

Based on https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.0/sampleconfig/orderer.yaml line 198 onwards, I think I need the following settings for my orderers:

```
- ORDERER_KAFKA_TLS_ENABLED=true
- ORDERER_KAFKA_TLS_PRIVATEKEY_FILE=<not sure which to use>
- ORDERER_KAFKA_TLS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=<certificate produced by the above key and signed by the below CA?>
- ORDERER_KAFKA_TLS_ROOTCAS_FILE=<the CA certificate in the kafka truststore produced in step 9?>
```

But it isn't clear to me how to produce those files since the orderer expects PEM but the stuff produced in step 9 are java keystores.

I've tried using some conversions with openssl but my orderers are constantly being rejected by the cluster.